# Job Application asking questions about high school credit hours

Tags: applications

A job I'm applying for is asking for credit/quarter hours for every educational institution I have attended. For college this is not a problem, but they are asking for credit hours from high school as well. My high school didn't have credit hours on their transcripts (it wasn't a public school) and I don't really see why it makes any difference. Should I just leave that space blank? Thank you.

Comment: Your high school diploma should be enough. You should verify that is indeed the case. It seems strange any employer would care about your high school transcripts if you have graduated from college.

Comment: Yes, it was strange. The place I'm applying to still uses paper applications, so I'm considering just writing a note on the application explaining the credits thing.

Comment: Write "N/A".  Done.

Answer (score 3):

This is certainly a... peculiar request. As others have stated - the first port of call is to talk to the Recruiter and enquire about it.

FWIW - No job that I've ever applied for, including the Minimum wage jobs I had *whilst I was in highschool* gave one iota about my School hours.

If they are really particular about it and you are really keen on the job (again, FWIW if any job asked for this info, unless they were offering me a Gold-plated Lamborghini as a company car, a private island for an Office and a Salary that would make Jeff Bezos jealous - it would go in the too-hard bin) - then I would offer to setup a conference call with the school and the recruiter so *they* can explain that they don't have this info.

But as you may have guessed from my aside above? My best answer is this - unusual and unreasonable requests are red flags in the interview process. Details about University, especially if it is for a field where a Degree is mandatory - that I could understand for an Intern or entry-level position. But High School?

Yeah, I'd be moving on.

Answer (score 1):

> My high school didn't have credit hours on their transcripts (it
> wasn't a public school) and I don't really see why it makes any
> difference. Should I just leave that space blank?

You have two choices. Answer it the best way you can; or try and reach out to the company.

I wouldn't leave it completely blank, but include as much as you can with the detail they want.

why do they want this? In some places there are different diploma levels. This may be their way of getting that information.

Comment: The closest I had to high school credits were some dual-enrollment courses I took at the local community college that transferred to college.

Answer (score 1):

You should check with the employer to find out how they want you to report this, but:

In my experience "credit hours" translates to "average total hours of study including homework, per week, for an average student." Most of my college classes were rated at 12 credit hours for each term; the "distribution" classes were typically 9 and gym/athletics were typically 6 (divided into half-term classes of 3 each).

You should be able to figure out at least an approximate unofficial number by remembering how many hours you spend in school and how many hours you spent on homework.

BUT check to make sure this is how the employer defines that term!

Comment: The classes are mentioned as being credit/quarter hours.